# How to sort by nested field value with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, sorting, mongoid, mongoid3, database-relations

Let's say I have a `User` with a field `name`, and which has_many `teams`, and a `Team` that belongs_to a `user`, and belongs_to a `sport`. A `Sport` has a field `name` and has_many `teams`.

I want to walk through the `sports`, do some stuff, and collect an array of the `teams` sorted by the `name` of the `user`.

```
result = []
Sport.asc(:name).each do |spt|
  # some other stuff not relevant to this question but that
  # justifies my looping through each sport.
  spt.teams.asc(:'user.name').each { |t| result << t }
end
```

This runs but and the sorting of the `sports` is as expected, but the order of the teams in `result` is not sorted as I'd expect.

What is the correct way, using `Mongoid` to sort a collection by the value of a relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this with Mongoid. It might work if the field you were sorting by was part of an *embedded* document, but not in this case where you're using a referenced document.

I guess you probably have two options here, the less efficient way would be to just sort the collection of teams in ruby:

```
sport.teams.sort{|t1, t2| t1.user.name <=> t2.user.name}.each{ |team| result << team }
```

The better, and arguably more 'MongoDB-y' solution, would be to cache the user name inside each team, using a `before_save` callback, and then use that to sort the teams:

```
# app/models/team.rb
class Team
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :user_name, :type => String

  before_save :update_user_name

  protected
  def update_user_name
    self.user_name = self.user.name if self.user
  end
end
```

Then you can just do:

```
spt.teams.asc(:user_name).each { |t| result << t }
```

Obviously, if the user's name field is mutable, then you'll to trigger it to save each child-team whenever the user's name field is changed.

```
class User
  after_save :update_teams_if_name_changed

  def update_teams_if_name_changed
    if self.name_changed?
      self.teams.each { |team| team.save }
    end
  end
end
```

Given that is not fantastically simple to maintain, this could arguably be a good candidate to use an observer, rather than callbacks, but you get the idea.